# Can I run nVidia's nView on Windows 7 x64?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, desktop

As the title suggests, I want to run nView desktop manager on Windows 7 x64. nView used to come bundled with the drivers back in the Windows XP days, but I can no longer find it.

Alternatively I would be happy if anyone knows of another 3rd party desktop manager. (preferrably one which allows me to span a 3840x1200 image across the screens)

I am using a GeForce GTX 460 and dual 1920x1200 monitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nView is only for Quadro video cards, the GTX460 is a GeForce and not supported with nView since the Vista update. You'll want to check for VirtuaWin or another application for the best experience with your current card.

Comment: Not quite, see here: http://superuser.com/questions/67459/nvidia-nview-manager-missing

Answer (score 0):

Installing Quadro driver with few lines added for corresponding device ID in nv_dispwi.inf, will be able to run nview. With 560 GTX I'm able to do this.